# Time complexity to delete a leaf node from Max Heap?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, heap, binary-heap

Let's say we're given with a MAX Heap and we want to delete any of the leaf node, then how much time will it take to delete any of the leaf node and maintain the max heap property?

My main doubt is - will it O(n) time to reach to leaf nodes?

Also, why Binary Heaps has to be a complete Binary Tree and not almost complete Binary tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary heap is a [complete binary tree](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html). All levels are full, except possibly the last, which is left-filled. A binary tree is not necessarily a *full* binary tree.

In a binary heap of size N, represented in an array, the leaf nodes are in the last half of the array. That is, the nodes from N/2 to N-1 are leaf nodes. Deleting the last node (i.e. `a[N-1]`) is an O(1) operation: all you have to do is remove the node and decrease the size of the heap.

Removing any other leaf node is potentially an O(log n) operation because you have to:

1. Move the last node, `a[N-1]` to the node that you're deleting.
2. Bubble that item up into the heap, to its proper position.

The first part is, of course, O(1). The second part can require up to `log(n) - 1` moves. The *average* is less than 2, but the worst case is `log(n) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a MAX heap you can access the leaf node in the heap in **O(logn)** as it is a complete binary tree and traversing the entire height of the tree takes  **O(logn)**
2. Once this is done, you can call heapify to build the heap again which takes **O(logn)**
3. Almost Complete Binary Tree is no different from Complete Binary Tree except that it has following two restrictions :

   At every node after completion of current level only go to next level.
   At every node after completion of left node go to right.

Every formula that is applicable to complete binary tree will be applicable to almost complete binary tree.

The only difference is there is a gap at last level from right to left in almost complete binary tree. If there is no gap then it is Complete Binary Tree.

Heap is forced to have this property of being a compete binary tree for effciency purposes